# Setting current time in input type time in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, model-view-controller, time

I am quite new to ASP.Net Core MVC. I am trying to display the current time  in input type time. But I am not able to do so. Below is the code I am trying.

```html
  <input type="time" id="starttime" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString("hh::mm::ss tt")" />
```

The time picker shows blank. I also tried by setting time by script  but no luck.

Could someone please help? Isnt it possible to display current time in this manner?

Comment: Q: Is your question answered/your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time): *"The control's user interface varies from browser to browser"*.

SUGGESTIONS:

1. Look at the actual HTML rendered in Chrome Dev Tools.
2. If the HTML looks OK, experiment with different ".ToString()" format patterns until your time picker looks OK, too.
3. Once it works on one browser (e.g. Chrome), be sure to also test on other browsers (e.g. IE11, Firefox, Safari and Edge).

FYI, I don't think the format "hh::mm::ss tt" is valid for any browser.

I tried these different format strings on Chrome:

```
Format         Status  Display:
------         ----    -------
hh::mm::ss tt  FAILS   --:-- --
hh:mm          OK      12:33 PM
hh:mm:ss       OK      12:33:38 PM
hh:mm:ss tt    FAILS   --:-- --
hh::mm         FAILS   --:-- --
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see that hh:mm works for chrome.

Comment: IMPORTANT POINTS: 1) "hh:mm" should work for ANY browser.On the other hand, "hh::mm::ss tt" is NOT a valid time format, and probably *WON'T* display a time value in most (all?) browsers. 2) As a web developer, you'll need to make it a point to *ALWAYS* test on *MULTIPLE DIFFERENT BROWSERS*.  ALSO: Please feel free to "upvote" and/or "accept" the answer if you found it helpful.